# Difficulty in parsing the XML

Tags: jquery, html, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have been doing some XML parsing in my application. I used the following syntax to get the data from XML to my array:

```
v3[p]=''+xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("volatility_analysis3")[p].childNodes[0].nodeValue+'.';
```

but the problem is there is no data present in that particular node. It's like

```
<volatility_analysis3></volatility_analysis3>
```

so the parsing ends there. How to overcome that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the length of `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("volatility_analysis3")`. If it is 0, move on.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in steps like this

```
var node = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("volatility_analysis3")[p];
if (node.hasChildNodes())
 {
   v3[p]=''+node.childNodes[0].nodeValue+'.';
 }
```

---

If you are not sure there are `p` number of `volatility_analysis3` nodes then add one more step

```
var nodelist = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("volatility_analysis3");
if (nodelist.length >= p )
 {
   var node = nodelist[p];
   if (node.hasChildNodes())
    {
      v3[p]=''+node.childNodes[0].nodeValue+'.';
    }
 }
```